# Records are not updated into database upon power failure

Tags: c#

From last some days i was working on one issue but could not found any solution for same. Issue is mentioned as below :

Issue :

Step 1 : I am working on windows base application and having backend as Microsoft SQL Express 2014 (12.0.2). Database is on same system.

Step 2 : My application works like printing and then inspection. In one of my table named as 'PackagingDetails' there are already records present. When I pass carton from conveyor first is gets printed (in that case field  'IsUsed' gets updated as 'true' from null.) and then depending upon inspection result field  'IsRejected' gets updated as 'true' or 'false' .

Step 3: As mentioned in step 2, application continues to work but in running when there is power failure occurs(no power backup) and system gets off. No records updated against passed cartons. (Neither 'IsUsed' field nor 'IsRejected').

Step 4 : We are using stored procedure for insertion and updating.

Comment: See database mirroring : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-sql-server

Comment: make sure your transactions are properly committed.
try running these stored procedures from the SQL Console and see if the results persists.

Comment: Are your SQL commands wrapped in a try/catch? If you can't connect to the DB maybe you could cache locally until it is available, possibly an SqLite setup

Comment: @ Usama - Yes transactions are committed properly and also i have used try catch block to check issues.

Comment: During testing i found that when i update any records then sql take come time for updation, during this time if i forcefully power off the system then no records gets updated. So i want to know that is there any settings in sql server to minimize the time required for updation.